# VS Tools for Universal Windows Apps 1.1 can't create app package anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

I Upgraded VS20154 to the  Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps. Local build works fine in debugg configuration. But when I try to create the app package I get this error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line

```
Manifest references file 'MoneyManager.Windows.dll' which is not part of the payload.   MoneyManager.Windows    C:\Users\ninop\Documents\GitHub\MoneyManager\Src\MoneyManager.Windows\Package.appxmanifest
```

Does anyhoner have an idea how to fix that?

Thanks
NPadrutt

Comment: Have you been able to build in Release mode locally? I get the same error whether it's the app package or just release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is an answer on the MSDN Forums:

> To workaround this issue, add the below ItemGroup in your project file and regenerate the package.
>
> `<ItemGroup>
>     <AppxSystemBinary Include="<Assembly Mentioned in the error>" />
>   </ItemGroup>`
>
> For example, if the assembly name is App1.dll, include:
>
> `<ItemGroup>
>    <AppxSystemBinary Include="App1.dll" />
>   </ItemGroup>`

From: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73f2d56d-9e8e-4b57-bcfa-0a972dfd75d7/update-11-generating-store-associated-package-fails-for-a-uwp-application-with-a-winrt-component?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues